# Why am I getting a core dump after deleting the pointer in function freeTheMemory?

Tags: c++, stack

I am working on a program that does basic push and pop on stacks. I've stepped through the program in GDB and everything works perfectly up until the program hits line fifth line in freeTheMemory function. Every time the program gets there, it gives me a core dump:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class linkedList{
public:
    int content;
    linkedList* pointerToBelow;
};

void freeTheMemory(linkedList *above){
    if(above!=nullptr){
        linkedList* temp;
        temp=above;
        above=above->pointerToBelow;
        delete temp;
        freeTheMemory(above);
    }
}

void push(linkedList* above, linkedList* below, int x){
    below->content=x;
    above->pointerToBelow=below;
    below=above;
    above=new linkedList;
    return;
}

void pop(linkedList* above, linkedList* below){
    linkedList* temp;
    temp=above;
    above=below;
    below=below->pointerToBelow;
    delete temp;
    return;
}

void printList(linkedList *above){
    linkedList* temp;
    temp=above;
    above=above->pointerToBelow;
    while(above!=nullptr){
        cout<<above->content<<" ";
        above=above->pointerToBelow;
    }
    above=temp;
}

int main(){
    linkedList *above, *below;
    int x;
    above=new linkedList;
    below=new linkedList;
    below->pointerToBelow=nullptr;
    cout<<"Enter the elements of your list: ";
    while(x!=-9){
        cin>>x;
        if(x!=-9){
            if(x>0){
                push(above, below, x);
            }
            else{
                pop(above, below);
            }
        }
    }
    printList(above);
    freeTheMemory(above);
    return 0;
}
```

If that's where I'm getting the core dump, is that where the problem is in my code? If so, does anyone have an idea of what is going wrong here?

Comment: You never initialize `pointerToBelow` when you create a new `linkedList`.

Comment: You have a memory leak in `push()`. You do `new linkedList` and assign it to a local variable, but never save it anywhere permanent.

Comment: I think he needs to use double asterisks, in the conventional C sense, or use the reference (&) operator since this is c++.

Comment: @Barmar can you explain further? The only variables in the function, above and below, were both passed there as pointers by main. Since I passed them as pointers from main, shouldn't that mean that those values for those variables exist in main? To make those variables not local, should I try what Shawnic Hedgehog suggested and use a double asterisk? Thanks

Comment: Arguments in C++ are passed by value unless you use references. Assigning to `above` in the function doesn't change the caller's variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution has logical flaws. It actually does not retain all elements in the stack because you are creating nodes and assigning their pointers to local variables and thus are not literally added to the linked list. Moreover, your code is unnecessarily complicated partly due to the use of two pointers. And thus it is hard for you to debug. Since you are using a linked list to implement a stack, I would argue that only one pointer is enough.

Below I have revised your solution. I keep a single pointer called `top` which is a dummy node pointing to the top of the stack. its `pointerToBelow` points to the real top element of the stack.

**At `push` do the following:**

1. Create a new node and set its `content` to `x`.
2. Set its `pointerToBelow` to the previous top element of the stack
3. Have the `pointerToBelow` of `top` point to this new node.

**At `pop` do the following:**

1. If there are no elements in the stack, just return, otherwise
2. Get `pointerToBelow` of `top` point to the element below the element at the top of the stack.
3. Delete the top element of the stack.

**At `pointerToBelow`** you don't necessarily need recursion, nevertheless. But that is OK.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class linkedList{

public:
  int content;
  linkedList* pointerToBelow;
};

void freeTheMemory(linkedList *top) {

  if(top != nullptr){
    linkedList* temp = top->pointerToBelow;
    delete top;
    freeTheMemory(temp); // temp is now the top
  }
}

void push(linkedList* top, int x){

  // create new node, assign x
  linkedList *node = new linkedList;
  node->content = x;

  // new node points to top element in the stack
  node->pointerToBelow = top->pointerToBelow;

  // top now points to the new node
  top->pointerToBelow = node;
}

void pop(linkedList* top ){

  linkedList* toDelete = top->pointerToBelow;

  // case 1: stack is empty
  if(toDelete == nullptr)
    return; // do nothing

  // case 2: deleting top element
  top->pointerToBelow = toDelete->pointerToBelow;
  delete toDelete;
}

void printList(linkedList *top) {
  top = top->pointerToBelow;

  while(top != nullptr) {
    cout << top->content << " ";
    top = top->pointerToBelow;
  }
}

int main(){

int x;
linkedList *top = new linkedList;

top->pointerToBelow = nullptr; // indicates stack is empty

cout<<"Enter the elements of your list: ";

while(x != -9) {
   cin >> x;

    if(x! =- 9) {
      if(x>0)
        push(top, x);
      else
        pop(top);
    }
  }

  printList(top);
  freeTheMemory(top);

  return 0;
}
```